# Rendering a table in React Native using API JSON data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm very new to React Native and really need some help!

I have some JSON data which I have loaded into my React Native Application in the format below:

```
Object {
  "company": "Company1",
  "lineItem": "Line1",
  "value": -1,
  "year": 2017,
},
Object {
  "company": "Company1",
  "lineItem": "Line2",
  "value": 55.5,
  "year": 2016,
},
Object {
  "company": "Company1",
  "lineItem": "Line3",...
```

I need to find a way to output that data in a table with the following structure in my React Native App:

[image: Table Output View]

The years in the data, as well as the row labels repeat, but will always be a distinct row label and year combination.

Any pointers or help would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can look into this popular [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-table-component) which allows you to create all kinds of tables you just need to transform your data a bit and pass it to the component and it will create the table just like you are looking for.

[image: Table in react native]

the library is quite flexible and many customization options are available you can explore more.